# libpcre throwing a ".rodata can not be used when making a shared object" error while compiling NGINX

Tags: nginx, compiler-errors, ubuntu-16.04, pcre

I am trying to compile NGINX on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, with these instructions:

https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-compile-nginx-from-source-on-ubuntu-16-04

Instead of `nginx-1.13.1`, I'm trying to do so with `nginx-1.13.8` (mainline), but during `make`, I'm running into an error with the `pcre` Library:

```
...
objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module.o \
objs/ngx_modules.o \
-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIC -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -ldl -lpthread -lpthread -lcrypt ../pcre-8.40/.libs/libpcre.a ../openssl-1.1.0f/.openssl/lib/libssl.a ../openssl-1.1.0f/.openssl/lib/libcrypto.a -ldl ../zlib-1.2.11/libz.a \
-Wl,-E
/usr/bin/ld: ../pcre-8.40/.libs/libpcre.a(libpcre_la-pcre_compile.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
../pcre-8.40/.libs/libpcre.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
objs/Makefile:328: recipe for target 'objs/nginx' failed
make[1]: *** [objs/nginx] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user1/nginx-1.13.8'
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

Even when trying to follow the instructions, and changing: (-fPIE)

```
--with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' \
--with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now'
```

to: (-fPIC)

```
--with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' \
--with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIC -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now'
```

the error still remains. How can I solve this issue? Ideally by only changing the `./configure` parameters? The system is a fresh setup so far.

Answer (score 5):

Try to include this configure options with nginx:

```
--with-pcre-opt='-g -Ofast -fPIC -m64 -march=native -fstack-protector-strong -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' \
--with-zlib-opt='-g -Ofast -fPIC -m64 -march=native -fstack-protector-strong -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' \
```

I've just managed to install nginx with this additional opt.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I'm attempting to build an Nginx installation with sticky session support from [sticky-module-ng](https://bitbucket.org/nginx-goodies/nginx-sticky-module-ng/src). Using the configure parameters from the Ubuntu Nginx build guide produces the pcre error. I tried the example parameters from [nginx.org](https://nginx.org/en/docs/configure.html) build guide with openssl  added and now I get no error.

```
./configure \
    --prefix=/usr/share/nginx \
    --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx \
    --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
    --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules \
    --build=Ubuntu \
    --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
    --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
    --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid \
    --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock \
    --with-http_ssl_module \
    --with-pcre=../pcre-8.40 \
    --with-zlib=../zlib-1.2.11 \
    --with-openssl=../openssl-1.1.0f
```

However I'm not familiar enough with Nginx to know whether I'm missing some critical parameters.

Answer (score 0):

got the same problem.  Solved it by

```
CFLAGS="-g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fPIC"
export CFLAGS
LDFLAGS=-fPIC
export LDFLAGS
```

then go into the ../pcre8.40 project

```
./configure
make
```

then go into the ../zlib-1.2.11 project

```
./configure
make
```

After this executing ./configure and make in the nginx project worked.